# Critique on jQuery Use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm busy introducing myself to jQuery by implementing a little system where onmouseover on an element causes a text balloon to pop up close to the element.  I feel like I'm using too much vanilla JS here, so please suggest where I can improve and what is wrong with this code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('span.balloon').each(function() {
                this.style.display = "none";        
            });      

            $('span.ballooned').mouseover(function(event){
                if (event.currentTarget.attributes["balloonid"]) {
                    var blnArr = $("#" + event.currentTarget.attributes["balloonid"].value);
                    if (blnArr.length > 0) {
                        blnArr[blnArr.length - 1].style.display = "inline";                    
                    };
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        This is some text where I describe a <span class="ballooned" balloonId="bln-1">text field</span> and want to attach extra info to that phrase.
    </div>
    <span class="balloon" id="bln-1">nvarchar(8)</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("span.balloon").hide();

    $("span.ballooned[balloonid]").mouseover(
        function() {
            var balloonid = "#" + $(this).attr("balloonid"); 
            $(balloonid).css("display", "inline");
        });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the [balloonid] mention, that's a part of the selector syntax that is massively underused

Answer (score 5):

First, let me say there is nothing wrong with using vanilla js, *if you're sure it isn't browser dependent*. The jQuery framework isn't intended to replace any and all javascript syntax. I think most people would say that jQuery is intended to 1) remedy a long standing issue of forcing developers to deal with a browser war we have no control over and 2) to simplify complex tasks that are regularly needed to meet the demands of the day.

That said, I would recommend you use [jQuery's CSS](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) functions to set the properties.

Comment: I'm not all against using plain js, but I'd rather learn to use jQuery to the full, and invent some new wheels.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('span.balloon').hide();

    $('span.ballooned').mouseover(function(event){
        if ( this.balloonid ) {
            var blnArr = $("#" + this.balloonid);
            if (blnArr[0]) {
                $( blnArr[blnArr.length - 1] ).css('display', 'inline');              
            };
        }
    });

});
```

... Not sure if that will work... I'm wondering: why are you using expando properties ("baloonid") - it's a bit obtrusive and messy.

Comment: be careful with this.baloonid, expando's like that aren't cross browser (I forget which browser bit me on this one, but it wasn't pretty!). .attr('baloonid') is safer

Comment: why not just if (blnArr.length)

Comment: Because [0] saves three characters.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the beauty of jQuery is that there's a plugin for anything you want to do. In the spirit of that, you should check out one of my favorite plugins: [jQuery BeautyTips](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html). It does balloons quite nicely.

Comment: Another jQuery plugin with similar functionality is clueTip

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.ballooned').mouseover(function(e){
  if ($(this).attr("balloonid")) 
    $("#" + $(this).attr("balloonid")).css('display','inline');
});
```